# how to overlap images CSS and make them look cut?

Tags: css, image

so im doing a front end challenge and basically i gotta do this[image: design photo of the challenge] and half way through images to move the images but i cant seem to make the cut/overlap

````css
```

:root {
--clr-bggrad-violet: hsl(273, 75%, 66%);
--clr-bggrad-blue: hsl(240, 73%, 65%);
--clr-text-dark: hsl(238, 29%, 16%);
--clr-text-red: hsl(14, 88%, 65%);
--clr-divider: hsl(240, 5%, 91%);
--ff-kumbh: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}


/* "*" helps the code to be vieweble on all broswers */
/* Box sizing rules */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Remove default margin */
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


body {
min-height: 100vh;
text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
line-height: 1.5;

font-family: var(--ff-kumbh);
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 0.8rem;
color: var(--clr-text-dark);
display: flex;
flex-flow: column nowrap;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
background: linear-gradient(var(--clr-bggrad-violet), var(--clr-bggrad-blue));
}

main {
position: relative;
background: url(images/bg-pattern-mobile.svg) no-repeat top center;
background-color: white;
display: flex;
flex-flow: column nowrap;
align-items: center;
border-radius: 1rem;
padding: 1rem;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
box-shadow: 0 10px 40px -15px var(--clr-text-dark);
}

.title {
padding: 1rem;
margin: 1rem;
font-weight: 700;
}



/* Make images easier to work with */
img,
picture {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
}

.hero-images {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-flow: column nowrap;
align-items: center;
margin-bottom: 7rem;
}

.hero {
position: absolute;
top: -7rem;
width: min(80%, 255px);
}

.box {
display: none;
}


@media (min-width: 900px) {
main {
    width: 870px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    background-image: unset;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0;
}

.hero-images {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background-image: url(images/illustration-woman-online-desktop.svg),
        url(images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 90%, 120%;
    background-position: -4.8rem 5rem, -12rem -2rem;
    margin: unset;
}

.box {
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    display: unset;
    top: 12rem;
    left: -5.5rem;
    z-index: 1;
}

.hero {
    display: none;
}

}
```
````

````html
```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <title>Frontend Mentor | FAQ Accordion Card</title>

</head>

<body>
  <main>


<picture class="box">
  <img src="images/illustration-box-desktop.svg" alt="TheBox" aria-hidden="true" />
</picture>



<section class="hero-images">

  <picture class="hero">
    <source media="(max-width: 900px)" srcset="images/illustration-woman-online-mobile.svg"
      alt="you see this first" />
    <img src="images/illustration-woman-online-desktop.svg" alt="ShrinkUseeThis" aria-hidden="true" />
  </picture>


</section>



<section>
  <h1 class="title">FAQ</h1>

  <div>
    <button class="btn dropBtn" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample"
      aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      How many team members can I invite?<img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="IconArrow" aria-hidden="true" />
    </button>
    </p>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
      <div class="card card-body">
        You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is
        no limit on team members for the Premium plan.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div>
    <button class="btn dropBtn" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample"
      aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      What is the maximum file upload size?<img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="IconArrow"
        aria-hidden="true" />
    </button>
    </p>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
      <div class="card card-body">
        No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted
        storage space.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div>
    <button class="btn dropBtn" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample"
      aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      How do I reset my password?<img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="IconArrow" aria-hidden="true" />
    </button>
    </p>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password”
        from your profile page. A reset link will be emailed to you.

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div>
    <button class="btn dropBtn" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample"
      aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      Can I cancel my subscription?<img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="IconArrow" aria-hidden="true" />
    </button>
    </p>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions
        asked.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>





  <div>
    <button class="btn dropBtn" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample"
      aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      Do you provide additional support?<img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="IconArrow" aria-hidden="true" />
    </button>
    </p>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open
        during normal business hours.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>







  <p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button"
      aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">Toggle first element</a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#multiCollapseExample2"
      aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2">Toggle second element</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".multi-collapse"
      aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1 multiCollapseExample2">Toggle both
      elements</button>
  </p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
        <div class="card card-body">
          Some placeholder content for the first collapse component of this multi-collapse example. This panel is
          hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample2">
        <div class="card card-body">
          Some placeholder content for the second collapse component of this multi-collapse example. This panel is
          hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>






  

</section>
  </main>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```
````

i have tried to use krita and just crop and upload the images as one but it loses resolution(it looks pixelated).i have been thinking using the bodyBG and make that a png but the white box is there in the middle.

edit2: so the images were in .svg couldnt uploaded to imgur so i have to change it to .png i think i might have scramble the snippet cuz the images are everywhere sorry it is my first time doing this XD. also i tried the left: -15%;width: 50%;height: auto; and nothing happen
this is what i see on my computer:
[compu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRGM6.jpg)

edit3: so i found out about content-visibility CSS and i am trying to see that instead of a cut i will try to make the image half invisible

edit4: so it was "picture" HTML i found a guy that use it on the challenge i cant find him anymore and i still dont understand how is making the cut butt it works sooooo whatever thx anyway

Comment: Can you add your code so we can see what you've done so far. Just having your css isnt enough, can we see your html as well ?

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but `alt` attributes should be human-readable descriptions of the contents of the image. These are used by assistive technology. I have no idea how a screenreader would pronounce the string `womenDesk`.

Comment: i sincerely dont know what you mean @Sean can you send me a tutorial or video that explain that with detail

Comment: You should add at least a width property to get this done. For example .womenDesk {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width:50%;
    height: auto;
    left: -15%;
}

Comment: Can you make your code into a runnable snippet - and that needs to include images we can actually see - as it's difficult at the moment to envisage what result you are getting - especially without any apparent sizing on the images and so much else being hard coded in pixel units. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example